# how can I get real-time number of sockets in use across a server from C program?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

is there a way apart from parsing `/proc/net/sockstat{,6}` ? I don't even have this file documented in my `man proc` (Linux ubuntu 3.8.0-29-generic)

Comment: Do you mean for a single process, or for *all* processes? In the first case, look for socket files in `/proc/<pid>/fd/`, in the second case look at the source for `netstat`.

Comment: it is "all". To me parsing /proc/net/sockstat{,6} appears tad easier than parsing netstat source :-) I was hoping there were better approach.

Comment: In the case of `/proc/net/sockstat` "the source is documentation" and it's a simple text file anyway. Hasn't changed in quite some time, so quite likely you don't have to change your code frequently. See also `net/ipv{4,6}/proc.c` in your kernel source tree.

Comment: 'Real-time' has a specific technical meaning in IT, and that isn't it. Don't misuse standard terminology.